# Flexslider with custom thumbnail slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I've tried to customize a Flexslider with a thumbnail slider by adding some information and a button in the thumbnail. If you click on the thumbnail, the slider slides to the right slide. But if you click on the added link(in the thumbnail) you don't go to a URL behind it.

How can I make this to work?

This is the code that i've been using:

```html
<div id="carousel">
  <ul class="slides cntr cb">
    <li>
      <div class="image"><img src="url" alt=""></div>
      <div class="info">
        <p>Title</p>
        <div class="more">
          <span>Date</span> | <a href="http://link.com" title="ticket">BUTTON</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li> 
    <li>
      <div class="image"><img src="url" alt=""></div>
      <div class="info">
        <p>Title</p>
        <div class="more">
          <span>Date</span> | <a href="http://link.com" title="ticket">BUTTON</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with a simple javascript onclick function, I don't now if this is the best way to fix it. But hey, it works for now

```html
onclick="window.open('http://www.url.com', '_self')"
```